# Remove XML white spaces and break lines when parsing

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get the XML as string but all the spaces appear in the end result, I tried Regex and a lot of answers from here but I did not succed. Here my code.

```
public class XMLManager
{
    private static XmlDocument xmlInfographic;
    private static TextAsset infographicXML;

    public XMLManager()
    {
        infographicXML = Resources.Load("XML/Infographic") as TextAsset;
        xmlInfographic = new XmlDocument();
        xmlInfographic.LoadXml(infographicXML.text);
    }

     public static string LoadInformation(int index)
     {
          return xmlInfographic.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Infographic/Info/Info" + index).InnerText;
     }
}
```

Here the XML file:

```
<Infographic>

  <Info>
    <Info0>
      • Something_0.
      • Something_0.
      • Something_0.
      • Something_0.
      • Something_0.
    </Info0>

    <Info1>
      • Something_1.
      • Something_1.
      • Something_1.
   </Info1>

  </Info>

</Infographic>
```

The current output is something like:

```
\r\n
      • Someting_1.
      • Someting_1.
      • Someting_1.
\r\n
```

What I need is:

```
• Someting_1.
• Someting_1.
• Someting_1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace new lines and spaces with the null char.

```
public class XMLManager
{
    private static XmlDocument xmlInfographic;
    private static TextAsset infographicXML;

    public XMLManager()
    {
        infographicXML = Resources.Load("XML/Infographic") as TextAsset;
        xmlInfographic = new XmlDocument();
        xmlInfographic.LoadXml(infographicXML.text);
    }

    public static string LoadInformation(int index)
    {
        return Cleanup(xmlInfographic.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Infographic/Info/Info" + index).InnerText);
    }

    private static string Cleanup(string input)
    {
        return input
            .Replace("\n", string.Empty)
            .Replace(" ", string.Empty)
            .Replace("\r", string.Empty); 
    }
}
```

Comment: this will tranform somethingh such `something 1` into `something1`. Very likely, not the desired output

Answer (score 0):

The answer above was correct, but you can write in a more concise way :

```
public static string LoadInformation(int index)
{
    return Cleanup(xmlInfographic.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Infographic/Info/Info" + index).InnerText).Replace("\r\n",string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
}
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)

Answer (score 0):

Please put trim() that should be enough.

return xmlInfographic.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Infographic/Info/Info" + index).InnerText;

should be

return xmlInfographic.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Infographic/Info/Info" + index).InnerText.trim();